# Sort NSArray of NSDictionary objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, sorting

I have retrieved some JSON data from an API and now have an NSArray full of NSDictionary objects. Each NSDictionary has a key/value pair of "name" and I want to sort the NSArray by that key/value pair.

I've done quite a bit of searching but none of the solutions I've come across seem to work in the new Swift language and I'm not sure if it's possibly a bug or not...

I've tried:

```
var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true))
```

But that won't compile stating "NSSortDescriptor is not convertible to [AnyObject]".

Any advice?

Comment: Read what the error says: it expects an array...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you must pass an array of sort descriptors (even if it's only one):

```
let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
let sortedResults = results.sortedArray(using: [descriptor])
```

---

original answer (for Swift 1 I believe):

```
var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```

Comment: Using xcode 6.1 this gives me an 'Cannot convert the expression's type '$T7?? to type 'NSSortDescriptor' because I defined the NSArray like this         
        var valores = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: file)
 Any advice please? Any help will be much welcome

Comment: Great! the only example working after searching for 2 days! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have this in Objective-C -> NSArray *array = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; Anybody knows the alternative in Swift?

Answer (score 12):

Rather than doing this the old way, why not embrace the new? The swift Array type has both `sort` and `sorted` methods. You can supply a closure as the sort function:

```
var sortedResults= results.sorted {
  (dictOne, dictTwo) -> Bool in 
  // put your comparison logic here
  return dictOne["name"]! > dictTwo["name"]!
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, this can be done on one line:  `var sortedResults= results.sorted { $0["name"]! > $1["name"]! }`

Comment: It can indeed, but I am guessing the OP is a little new to Swift, so I opted for a more verbose closure syntax!

Comment: I am indeed new to Swift and I did try this earlier but couldn't make it work. I think I see what I missed though and will give your answer a shot later on. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked but I had all kinds of trouble bridging from NSArray to Array... Kambala's answer below worked though so I could keep using the NSArray.

Comment: How would you do the same with multiple sort descriptors?

Comment: Fantastic solution! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "", ascending: true)
   var sortDescriptors: NSArray = [arrDescriptor]
   _sortedArray = allKeysArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(sortDescriptors as [AnyObject])

   print(_sortedArray)
```