# How to Sort an array in an ascending order swift 2.3

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, sorting

```
[{
msg = "Hi This is Jecky";
name = Susheel;
sender = 77;
timestamp = 1464241769520;
username = susheel;
}, {
msg = Dubai;
name = Jecky;
sender = 78;
timestamp = 1464246547147;
username = Jecky;
}, {
msg = "How are you ?";
name = Susheel;
sender = 77;
timestamp = 1464243480381;
username = susheel;
}, {
msg = "Aje dekhai nai";
name = Jecky;
sender = 78;
timestamp = 1464244974198;
username = Jecky;
}]
```

- I have an array like this. I want to sort this array using timestamp in swift 2.3 or latest version of swift. Can anyone help me for this ?

Comment: Ascending order of what? Name? Timestamp? Username?

Comment: sorry dude i forgot that. It's timestamp

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24685377/3202193

Comment: This is an Array not NSArray so Sortdescriptor won't work here.

Comment: this is what i want exactly!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let array=[
        [
            "msg":"Hi This is Jecky",
            "name":"Susheel",
            "sender":77,
            "timestamp":1464241769520,
            "username":"susheel",
        ],
        [
            "msg":"Dubai",
            "name":"Jecky",
            "sender":78,
            "timestamp":1464246547147,
            "username":"Jecky",
        ],
        [
            "msg":"How are you ?",
            "name":"Susheel",
            "sender":77,
            "timestamp":1464243480381,
            "username":"susheel",
        ],
        [
            "msg":"Aje dekhai nai",
            "name":"Jecky",
            "sender":78,
            "timestamp":1464244974198,
            "username":"Jecky",
        ],
    ]
    print("array = \(array)")
    let sortedArray=array.sort { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
        return (obj1["timestamp"] as! Double) < (obj2["timestamp"] as! Double)
    }
    print("sortedArray = \(sortedArray)")
```

Answer (score 7):

If your array is mutable you can user `sortInPlace`

```
yourArray.sortInPlace{$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}
```

and if not, you can create a new array from sort, like suggested by Kristijan (although no need for parentheses on trailing closures):

```
let newArray = yourArray.sort{$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this functionality using extension:

```
extension NSArray{
 //sorting- ascending
  func ascendingArrayWithKeyValue(key:String) -> NSArray{
    let ns = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: key, ascending: true)
    let aa = NSArray(object: ns)
    let arrResult = self.sortedArray(using: aa as! [NSSortDescriptor])
    return arrResult as NSArray
  }

  //sorting - descending
  func discendingArrayWithKeyValue(key:String) -> NSArray{
    let ns = NSSortDescriptor.init(key: key, ascending: false)
    let aa = NSArray(object: ns)
    let arrResult = self.sortedArray(using: aa as! [NSSortDescriptor])
    return arrResult as NSArray
  }
}
```

use like this:

```
 let array=[
      [
        "msg":"Hi This is Jecky",
        "name":"Susheel",
        "sender":77,
        "timestamp":1464241769520,
        "username":"susheel",
        ],
      [
        "msg":"Dubai",
        "name":"Jecky",
        "sender":78,
        "timestamp":1464246547147,
        "username":"Jecky",
        ],
      [
        "msg":"How are you ?",
        "name":"Susheel",
        "sender":77,
        "timestamp":1464243480381,
        "username":"susheel",
        ],
      [
        "msg":"Aje dekhai nai",
        "name":"Jecky",
        "sender":78,
        "timestamp":1464244974198,
        "username":"Jecky",
        ],
      ]

    let a = NSArray.init(array: array)
    let filArray = a.ascendingArrayWithKeyValue(key: "timestamp")
    print(filArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
customArray.sortInPlace { 
  (element1, element2) -> Bool in
   return element1.someSortableField < element2.someSortableField
}
```

Check this out 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-sort-an-array-using-sort

Answer (score 1):

To sort by property "timestamp"

```
array.sorted{$1["timestamp"] as? Long > $0["timestamp"] as? Long}
```

Answer (score 0):

=> First, convert your Json to Objects. (check this link to do that :- http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/10/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-2/ )

=> Then declare your Array as a typed array so that you can call methods when you iterate:

```
var array : [yourObjectClassName] = []
```

=> Then you can simply sort the value by :

```
array.sort({ $0.name > $1.name })
```

The above example sorts all the arrays by name. If you need to sort by timeStamp you can change the name to timeStamp ..etc

Check this link for more sorting examples : [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Comment: This does not look like JSON.

Comment: i was refering @fnc12 answer and taught it was json :p